# Deque iterator not dereferencable when using pop function on not empty container

Tags: c++, debugging

So I was trying to debug using visual studio for my project, but I ran into this problem where the debugger says "deque iterator not dereferencable".
I am sure that before I use the pop function there is element in the deque container.

```
void Letterman::morph()
{
string current_word = start;
deque<string> routing;
routing.push_back(start);
for (size_t i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); i++)
{
    if (queue)
    {
        current_word = routing.front();
        routing.pop_front();
    }
```

Comment: Error on which line of code?

Comment: You may push one element, but you're pop()ing inside a for loop.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What's `dictionary` and how does it relate to `routing`? What's `queue`? Etc. Also, post the full error message and indicate on which line it's happening.

Comment: It's hard to tell because your `Letterman::morph` function is incomplete here.